# IBM Worklight Server 6.1 Installation - post-install failed

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server

Trying to install `IBM Worklight 6.1 server` fails, giving `post-install error` on *Windows 7 64bit.*

```
Installation manager version 1.6.3.1
Ant (1.9.2) also tried with 1.8.4

Application server Tomcat 8
```

===failed-install log====

Detected Java version: 1.6 in: D:\Program Files\IBM\Installation Manager\eclipse\jre_6.0.0.sr9_20110208_03\jre
Detected OS: Windows 7
parsing buildfile D:\Program Files\IBM\Worklight\WorklightServer\post-install.xml with URI = file:/D:/Program%20Files/IBM/Worklight/WorklightServer/post-install.xml
Project base dir set to: D:\Program Files\IBM\Worklight\WorklightServer
parsing buildfile

```
jar:file:/D:/Program%20Files/IBM/Installation%20Manager/eclipse/plugins/org.apache.ant_1.8.3.v20120321-1730/lib/ant.jar!/org/apache/tools/ant/antlib.xml with URI = jar:file:/D:/Program%20Files/IBM/Installation%20Manager/eclipse/plugins/org.apache.ant_1.8.3.v20120321-1730/lib/ant.jar!/org/apache/tools/ant/antlib.xml from a zip file
 [macrodef] creating macro  ant-loop
 [macrodef] creating macro  call-wsadmin
 [macrodef] creating macro  deploy-webapp-into-tomcat
 [macrodef] creating macro  undeploy-webapp-from-tomcat
 [macrodef] creating macro  copy-confidential-file
 [macrodef] creating macro  create-user-read-protected-dir
 [macrodef] creating macro  protect-allfiles-in-destination-dir
 [macrodef] creating macro  sql-derby-statement
 [macrodef] creating macro  sql-derby-file
 [macrodef] creating macro  sql-file
 [macrodef] creating macro  ant-escape
 [macrodef] creating macro  wsadmin-escape
 [macrodef] creating macro  argpart-escape
 [macrodef] creating macro  arg-escape
```

Build sequence for target(s) `ant-loop-callee' is [ant-loop-callee]
Complete build sequence is [ant-loop-callee, swallow-update-properties, init0, init1, init2, init3, init, show-properties, unconfigure-shortcuts, was-undeploy, undeploy-appcenter, unconfigure-appserver, uninstall-cleanup, uninstall, cleanup, configure-appcenter-database=derby, was-deploy, configure-appcenter-database=db2, main, undeploy-appcenter-from-appserver=was, undeploy-appcenter-from-appserver=was85liberty, ant-loop-inside-installation-manager.part2.if-install, configure-shortcuts, deploy-appcenter-into-appserver=tomcat, safe-uninstall, ant-loop-inside-installation-manager.part1, ant-loop-inside-installation-manager.part2.if-not-install, ant-loop-inside-installation-manager.part3.if-install-failed, ant-loop-inside-installation-manager.part3.if-not-install-failed, ant-loop-inside-installation-manager, deploy-appcenter-into-appserver=none, undeploy-appcenter-from-appserver=tomcat, undeploy-appcenter-from-appserver=none, ant-loop-standalone, configure-config-tool, safe-foo, configure-appserver=was85liberty, unconfigure-appserver=tomcat, restore-embedded-server-location, delete-update-properties, configure-appcenter-database, configure-appserver, deploy-appcenter, fix-permissions-in-scripts, install, safe-install, configure-appserver=tomcat, sql-derby-file-callee, sql-derby-statement-callee, protect-one-file, deploy-appcenter-into-appserver=was85liberty, configure-appserver=none, configure-appcenter-database=none, unconfigure-appserver=was85liberty, unconfigure-appserver=none, call-wsadmin-callee, deploy-appcenter-into-appserver=was, configure-appcenter-database=oracle, configure-appserver=was, configure-appcenter-database=mysql, unconfigure-appserver=was, ]

ant-loop-callee:
parsing buildfile jar:file:/D:/Program%20Files/IBM/Worklight/WorklightServer/uninstall/ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar!/net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml with URI = jar:file:/D:/Program%20Files/IBM/Worklight/WorklightServer/uninstall/ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar!/net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml from a zip file
parsing buildfile jar:file:/D:/Program%20Files/IBM/Worklight/WorklightServer/uninstall/ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar!/net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml with URI = jar:file:/D:/Program%20Files/IBM/Worklight/WorklightServer/uninstall/ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar!/net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml from a zip file
Project base dir set to: D:\Program Files\IBM\Worklight\WorklightServer
  [antcall] calling target(s) [install] in build file D:\Program Files\IBM\Worklight\WorklightServer\post-install.xml
parsing buildfile D:\Program Files\IBM\Worklight\WorklightServer\post-install.xml with URI = file:/D:/Program%20Files/IBM/Worklight/WorklightServer/post-install.xml
Project base dir set to: D:\Program Files\IBM\Worklight\WorklightServer

```
[macrodef] creating macro  ant-loop
 [macrodef] creating macro  call-wsadmin
 [macrodef] creating macro  deploy-webapp-into-tomcat
 [macrodef] creating macro  undeploy-webapp-from-tomcat
 [macrodef] creating macro  copy-confidential-file
 [macrodef] creating macro  create-user-read-protected-dir
 [macrodef] creating macro  protect-allfiles-in-destination-dir
 [macrodef] creating macro  sql-derby-statement
 [macrodef] creating macro  sql-derby-file
 [macrodef] creating macro  sql-file
 [macrodef] creating macro  ant-escape
 [macrodef] creating macro  wsadmin-escape
 [macrodef] creating macro  argpart-escape
```

Override ignored for property "argpart-escape.doublequote.escaped"
 [macrodef] creating macro  arg-escape
Build sequence for target(s) `install' is [restore-embedded-server-location, delete-update-properties, init0, init1, show-properties, init2, init3, init, configure-appcenter-database, configure-appserver, deploy-appcenter, was-deploy, fix-permissions-in-scripts, configure-config-tool, configure-shortcuts, cleanup, install]
Complete build sequence is [restore-embedded-server-location, delete-update-properties, init0, init1, show-properties, init2, init3, init, configure-appcenter-database, configure-appserver, deploy-appcenter, was-deploy, fix-permissions-in-scripts, configure-config-tool, configure-shortcuts, cleanup, install, swallow-update-properties, unconfigure-shortcuts, was-undeploy, undeploy-appcenter, unconfigure-appserver, uninstall-cleanup, uninstall, configure-appcenter-database=derby, configure-appcenter-database=db2, main, undeploy-appcenter-from-appserver=was, undeploy-appcenter-from-appserver=was85liberty, ant-loop-inside-installation-manager.part2.if-install, deploy-appcenter-into-appserver=tomcat, safe-uninstall, ant-loop-inside-installation-manager.part1, ant-loop-inside-installation-manager.part2.if-not-install, ant-loop-inside-installation-manager.part3.if-install-failed, ant-loop-inside-installation-manager.part3.if-not-install-failed, ant-loop-inside-installation-manager, deploy-appcenter-into-appserver=none, undeploy-appcenter-from-appserver=tomcat, undeploy-appcenter-from-appserver=none, ant-loop-standalone, safe-foo, configure-appserver=was85liberty, unconfigure-appserver=tomcat, safe-install, configure-appserver=tomcat, sql-derby-file-callee, sql-derby-statement-callee, protect-one-file, deploy-appcenter-into-appserver=was85liberty, configure-appserver=none, configure-appcenter-database=none, unconfigure-appserver=was85liberty, unconfigure-appserver=none, call-wsadmin-callee, ant-loop-callee, deploy-appcenter-into-appserver=was, configure-appcenter-database=oracle, configure-appserver=was, configure-appcenter-database=mysql, unconfigure-appserver=was, ]
  [antcall] Entering D:\Program Files\IBM\Worklight\WorklightServer\post-install.xml...
Build sequence for target(s)`install' is [restore-embedded-server-location, delete-update-properties, init0, init1, show-properties, init2, init3, init, configure-appcenter-database, configure-appserver, deploy-appcenter, was-deploy, fix-permissions-in-scripts, configure-config-tool, configure-shortcuts, cleanup, install]
Complete build sequence is [restore-embedded-server-location, delete-update-properties, init0, init1, show-properties, init2, init3, init, configure-appcenter-database, configure-appserver, deploy-appcenter, was-deploy, fix-permissions-in-scripts, configure-config-tool, configure-shortcuts, cleanup, install, swallow-update-properties, unconfigure-shortcuts, was-undeploy, undeploy-appcenter, unconfigure-appserver, uninstall-cleanup, uninstall, configure-appcenter-database=derby, configure-appcenter-database=db2, main, undeploy-appcenter-from-appserver=was, undeploy-appcenter-from-appserver=was85liberty, ant-loop-inside-installation-manager.part2.if-install, deploy-appcenter-into-appserver=tomcat, safe-uninstall, ant-loop-inside-installation-manager.part1, ant-loop-inside-installation-manager.part2.if-not-install, ant-loop-inside-installation-manager.part3.if-install-failed, ant-loop-inside-installation-manager.part3.if-not-install-failed, ant-loop-inside-installation-manager, deploy-appcenter-into-appserver=none, undeploy-appcenter-from-appserver=tomcat, undeploy-appcenter-from-appserver=none, ant-loop-standalone, safe-foo, configure-appserver=was85liberty, unconfigure-appserver=tomcat, safe-install, configure-appserver=tomcat, sql-derby-file-callee, sql-derby-statement-callee, protect-one-file, deploy-appcenter-into-appserver=was85liberty, configure-appserver=none, configure-appcenter-database=none, unconfigure-appserver=was85liberty, unconfigure-appserver=none, call-wsadmin-callee, ant-loop-callee, deploy-appcenter-into-appserver=was, configure-appcenter-database=oracle, configure-appserver=was, configure-appcenter-database=mysql, unconfigure-appserver=was, ]

```
restore-embedded-server-location:
[available] Unable to find file server_rename.properties

delete-update-properties:
[available] Unable to find file update.properties

init0:
[available] Found directory: D:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0
[available] Found file: D:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\conf\tomcat-users.xml
[available] Found directory: C:\ProgramData\IBM\Worklight\derby

init1:
 [property] Loading Environment env.
     [exec] Current OS is Windows 7
     [exec] Output redirected to property: windows.user.name
     [exec] Error redirected to property: user.err
     [exec] Executing 'uninstall\user.exe'
     [exec] The ' characters around the executable and arguments are
     [exec] not part of the command.
     [exec] Current OS is Windows 7
     [exec] Output redirected to property: windows.group.administrators
     [exec] Error redirected to property: sid-name.err
     [exec] Executing 'install\sid-name.exe' with arguments:
     [exec] 'S-1-5-32-544'
     [exec] 
     [exec] The ' characters around the executable and arguments are
     [exec] not part of the command.
```

[available] Found file: D:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\lib\catalina-ant.jar
  [antcall] Exiting D:\Program Files\IBM\Worklight\WorklightServer\post-install.xml.

BUILD FAILED
D:\Program Files\IBM\Worklight\WorklightServer\post-install.xml:332: The following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\Program Files\IBM\Worklight\WorklightServer\post-install.xml:1501:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: JVMCFRE003 bad major version; class=org/apache/catalina/ant/DeployTask, offset=6
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:275)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.defineClassFromData(AntClassLoader.java:1128)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.getClassFromStream(AntClassLoader.java:1299)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.findClassInComponents(AntClassLoader.java:1355)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.findClass(AntClassLoader.java:1315)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.loadClass(AntClassLoader.java:1068)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:619)
    at java.lang.Class.forNameImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:172)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Definer.addDefinition(Definer.java:594)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Definer.execute(Definer.java:239)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor8.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
    at net.sf.antcontrib.logic.IfTask.execute(IfTask.java:197)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor19.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.TaskAdapter.execute(TaskAdapter.java:154)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor8.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
    at net.sf.antcontrib.logic.Switch$Case.execute(Switch.java:171)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at net.sf.antcontrib.logic.Switch.execute(Switch.java:138)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor8.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:392)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:413)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(SingleCheckExecutor.java:38)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:442)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.CallTarget.execute(CallTarget.java:105)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor8.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:392)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:413)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:811)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:217)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
```

Total time: 3 seconds

Comment: It'd be better if you add full steps of HOW you've tried to install Worklight and provide FULL error log or messages... What did you do? Edit the question.

Comment: i have updated the post with failed-install details.

Answer (score 1):

From the error message 'java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: JVMCFRE003 bad major version; class=org/apache/catalina/ant/DeployTask, offset=6' it seems that a part of the Installer was interpreted with a Java older than 6.0.
I failed to see from the log file why this happened, but it seems that a java 5 or older was in the PATH and has been used instead of a Java 6 or more.